# Migrating from log4j 1.x to log4j 2 : Stack trace format

Tags: java, log4j2

I have upgraded loggers from log4j1.x to log4j2, but getting when it logs stack trace (~[bin/:?]) this is getting appended at the end.

Stack trace :-

```
18-07-2023 01:01:54 [ERROR] demo.Test.java (Method : testLogger:53) >>> arithmatic exc :- java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.zycus.crawler.driver.NewCommonDriver.testLogger(NewCommonDriver.java:13748) ~[bin/:?]
    at com.zycus.crawler.driver.NewCommonDriver.getPages(NewCommonDriver.java:626) ~[bin/:?]
    at com.zycus.crawler.driver.NewCommonDriver.main(NewCommonDriver.java:14029) ~[bin/:?]
```

I search on google but didn't found how to remove (~[bin/:?]) this part.
What need to do to remove it?
Thanks

I tried by passing Class name in logger object initialization but it didn't worked.

Comment: How have you initialised your logger variable in the class?

Answer (score 0):

The `~[bin/:?]` is packaging information added by the **`xEx`** pattern converter (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#pattern-layout)). It includes information about the JAR that contains the class:

> At the end of each stack element of the exception, a string containing the name of the jar file that contains the class or the directory the class is located in and the "Implementation-Version" as found in that jar's manifest will be added. If the information is uncertain, then the class packaging data will be preceded by a tilde, i.e. the `~` character.

Your code isn't packaged yet, so you get `~[bin/:?]`.

If you want a "standard" stacktrace, add `%n%ex` at the end of your pattern.